# How do I merge two similar database-schema in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, primary-key, database-schema

The database-schema (Source and target) are very large (each has over 350 tables). I have got the task to somehow merge these two tables into one. The data itself (whats in the tables) has to be migrated. I have to be careful that there are no double entries for primary keys before or while merging the schemata. Has anybody ever done that already and would be able to provide me his solution or could anyone help me get a approach to the task? My approaches all failed and my advisor just tells me to get help online :/

To my approach:
I have tried using the "all_constraints" table to get all pks from my db.

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cols.owner = 'DB'
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'  
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

I also "know" that there has to be a sequence for the primary keys to add values to it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_pk_addition
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
```

Because I am a noob if it comes to pl/sql (or sql in general)
So how/what I should do next? :/

> Here is a link for an ERD of the database:  https://ufile.io/9tdoj
>
> virus scan: https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/dbe5f418115e50313a2268fb33a924cc8cb57a43bc85b3bbf5f6a571b184627e/detection

Comment: `I am a noob if it comes to pl/sql` Not relevant but if you are `noob` you must learn to say `NO` to task given to you out of your expertise. Btw there are many tools for replication, try googling. Or you can build dynamic `MERGE` statement to achieve this

Comment: If I say NO I don't want to do this task I have to live with the consequences (beeing me not getting my degree) because my advisors won't care if you can do it or not, they want you to do it! That is the reason why I am asking the question online :/ And I can not use any other software else then sql-developer! But thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Ok ,,So you wanted to say. you have schema 1 with 350 tables and you want to merge these tables with schema 2 tables. Is my understanding correct ? Or you meant to say you have 1 schema and there are 350 tables names source and target and you want to merge them. Please revalidate, so that i could help .

Comment: I have two schemata which the tables (over 350 in each one) are similar to each other. Only the records (of each table) are different. One of the to schemata is called "Source" and the other one "Target".

Comment: That is one ***** adviser. I suggest for you to not overstay at this company. Advisers should be a role-models, a source of inspiration, a leader. Believe me, there are that kind of people<Off topic message>

Comment: I am just doing an internship for 2 months at this company. The thing is that I will get a degree if I successfully complete all tasks in these 2 months. If not I am either going to get a bad degree or no degree :( Because it is an internship I don't get paid. I am basically a slave for the next 2 months...

Comment: @AnSuS, what kind of migration has to be done? The data itself (whats in tables) or the tables structures (and data itself)? Which is the end schema - where the results has to be? Target schema? Can you provide a simplified demo data (few tables, few data) and what is the expected result?

Comment: @Ychdziu The data itself (whats in the tables) has to be migrated. I have edited my Post with a link to an ERD for a overlook of the tables. Hope that helps.

Comment: Are both schemata on the same database? And is the table structure really identical or only similar?

Comment: You need to just append the data from one schema to another or do you need to Merge the data between two schemas?  If Merge is needed then do you have the unique keys available?

Comment: @wolφi sorry for not being specific enough. The Schemata are on different databases and the table structure is identical.

Comment: @vishad I need to merge the data between two schemata. But I can also just append the data from one schemata into another. As long as the two schemata are merged there will be no problem! What do you mean with unique keys available?

Comment: If you need to Merge the data then you will need to update the existing rows in the target schema with the data in source schema, for updating the rows you will need to identify some unique keys on the basis of which you can do  a join (we can use primary key also).
If you need to append the data then you just need to insert the data from one schema to another which would be a simple insert operation

Comment: how about if a data from primary key of a table is contained in the other table, but the rest of the columns differ? what data will you keep? is there any timestamp field which might give information which table was updated last?

Comment: If the table structures are identical, lookup the MERGE statement example.Try to build up with one table, test it. If you will have any questions or will face some problems - ask them - we will help you - you are not alone. But you have to do the work - for the sake of learning and understanding of WHAT and WHY are you doing.

Comment: @vishad Ok now I understand what you mean. I need to merge the data that the primary keys have to be adjusted with each other. Meaning if I merge source schema with target schema they have no double entries in primary keys (which wouldn't work anyway because primary keys have to be unique). But I don't know how to do so... I think it is done by a trigger but I am not sure!

Comment: @Ychdziu Thank you very much you give me hope :)

Comment: @AnSuS: I'm afraid I can't help with your question, but I will say that your English is fine and you should not feel any need to apologize for it. Had you not mentioned you were not a native English speaker I wouldn't have known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As promised to help in my comment, i had prepared a dynamic code which you can try to get the data `merged` with the source and target tables. The logic is as below:

Step1: Get all the table names from the `SOURCE` schema. In the query below you can you need to replace the schema(owner) name respectively. For testing purpose i had taken only 1 table so when you run it,remove the table name filtering clause.

Step2: Get the constrained columns names for the table. This is used to prepared the `ON` clause which would be later used for `MERGE` statement.

Step3: Get the non-constrainted column names for the table. This would be used in `UPDATE` clause while using `MERGE`.

Step4: Prepare the `insert` list when the data doesnot match `ON` conditon of `MERGE` statement.

Read my inline comments to understand each step.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_TABLE
AS
Type OBJ_NME is table of varchar2(100) index by pls_integer;

--To hold Table name
v_obj_nm OBJ_NME ;

--To hold Columns of table
v_col_nm OBJ_NME;

v_othr_col_nm OBJ_NME;
on_clause VARCHAR2(2000);
upd_clause VARCHAR2(4000);
cntr number:=0;
v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);

col_list1  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list2  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list3  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list4  varchar2(4000);
col_list5  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list6  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list7  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list8  varchar2(4000);

BEGIN

--Get Source table names
SELECT OBJECT_NAME
BULK COLLECT INTO v_obj_nm
FROM all_objects 
WHERE owner LIKE  'RU%' -- Replace `RU%` with your Source schema name here
AND object_type = 'TABLE'
and object_name ='TEST'; --remove this condition if you want this to run for all tables

FOR I IN 1..v_obj_nm.count
loop
--Columns with Constraints 
  SELECT column_name
  bulk collect into v_col_nm 
  FROM user_cons_columns
  WHERE table_name = v_obj_nm(i);  

--Columns without Constraints remain columns of table
SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO v_othr_col_nm
from (
      SELECT column_name 
      FROM user_tab_cols
      WHERE table_name = v_obj_nm(i)
      MINUS
      SELECT column_name  
      FROM user_cons_columns
      WHERE table_name = v_obj_nm(i));

--Prepare Update Clause  
 FOR l IN 1..v_othr_col_nm.count
  loop
   cntr:=cntr+1;
   upd_clause := 't1.'||v_othr_col_nm(l)||' = t2.' ||v_othr_col_nm(l);    
   upd_clause:=upd_clause ||' and ' ;

   col_list1:= 't1.'||v_othr_col_nm(l) ||',';
   col_list2:= col_list2||col_list1;   

   col_list5:= 't2.'||v_othr_col_nm(l) ||',';
   col_list6:= col_list6||col_list5;

   IF (cntr = v_othr_col_nm.count)
   THEN 
    --dbms_output.put_line('YES');
     upd_clause:=rtrim(upd_clause,' and');
     col_list2:=rtrim( col_list2,',');
     col_list6:=rtrim( col_list6,',');
   END IF;
     dbms_output.put_line(col_list2||col_list6); 
   --dbms_output.put_line(upd_clause);
   End loop;
  --Update caluse ends     

   cntr:=0; --Counter reset  

 --Prepare ON clause  
  FOR k IN 1..v_col_nm.count
  loop
   cntr:=cntr+1;
   --dbms_output.put_line(v_col_nm.count || cntr);
   on_clause := 't1.'||v_col_nm(k)||' = t2.' ||v_col_nm(k);    
   on_clause:=on_clause ||' and ' ;

   col_list3:= 't1.'||v_col_nm(k) ||',';
   col_list4:= col_list4||col_list3;    

   col_list7:= 't2.'||v_col_nm(k) ||',';
   col_list8:= col_list8||col_list7;    

   IF (cntr = v_col_nm.count)
   THEN 
    --dbms_output.put_line('YES');
    on_clause:=rtrim(on_clause,' and');
    col_list4:=rtrim( col_list4,',');
    col_list8:=rtrim( col_list8,',');
   end if;

   dbms_output.put_line(col_list4||col_list8);
 -- ON clause ends

 --Prepare merge Statement

    v_sql:= 'MERGE INTO '|| v_obj_nm(i)||' t1--put target schema name before v_obj_nm
              USING (SELECT * FROM '|| v_obj_nm(i)||') t2-- put source schema name befire v_obj_nm here 
              ON ('||on_clause||')
              WHEN MATCHED THEN
              UPDATE
              SET '||upd_clause ||              
              ' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
              INSERT  
              ('||col_list2||','
                ||col_list4||
              ')
              VALUES
              ('||col_list6||','
                ||col_list8||          
               ')';

      dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);   
      execute immediate v_sql;
  end loop;    
End loop;
END;
/
```

Execution:

```
exec COPY_TABLE
```

Output:

```
anonymous block completed
```

PS: i have tested this with a table with 2 columns out of which i was having unique key constraint .The DDL of table is as below:

At the end i wish you could understand my code(you being a noob) and implement something similar if the above fails for your requirement.

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST
       (    COL2 NUMBER, 
            COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
            CONSTRAINT TEST_UK1 UNIQUE (COLUMN1)  
       ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort :) I am going to try it our as soon as I am back at my workplace!

Comment: I have got some errors trying to create the procedure. How can I message you the errors they are to long to be a comment...?

Comment: @AnSuS Edit your question and post it there.

Answer (score 2):

**Oh dear!** Normally, such a question would be quickly closed as "too broad", but we need to support victims of evil advisors!

As for the effort, I would need a week full time for an experienced expert plus two days quality checking for an experierenced QA engineer.

First of all, there is no way that such a complex data merge will work on the first try. That means that you'll need test copies of both schemas that can be easily rebuild. And you'll need a place to try it out. Normally this is done with an export of both schemas and an empty dev database.

Next, you need both schemas close enough to be able to compare the data. I'd do it with an import of the export files mentione above. If the schema names are identical than rename one during import.

Next, I'd doublecheck if the structure is really identical, with queries like

```
 SELECT a.owner, a.table_name, b.owner, b.table_name
   FROM all_tables a 
   FULL JOIN all_tables b 
     ON a.table_name = b.table_name
    AND a.owner = 'SCHEMAA' 
    AND b.owner = 'SCHEMAB'
  WHERE a.owner IS NULL or b.owner IS NULL;
```

Next, I'd check if the primary and unique keys have overlaps:

```
 SELECT id FROM schemaa.table1
 INTERSECT
 SELECT id FROM schemab.table1;
```

As there are 300+ tables, I'd generate those queries:

```
 DECLARE 
   stmt VARCHAR2(30000);
   n NUMBER;
   schema_a CONSTANT VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) := 'SCHEMAA';
   schema_b CONSTANT VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) := 'SCHEMAB';
 BEGIN
   FOR c IN (SELECT owner, constraint_name, table_name,
                    (SELECT LISTAGG(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY position)
                       FROM all_cons_columns c
                      WHERE s.owner = c.owner
                        AND s.constraint_name = c.constraint_name) AS cols
               FROM all_constraints s
              WHERE s.constraint_type IN ('P') 
                AND s.owner = schema_a) 
   LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('Checking pk '||c.constraint_name||' on table '||c.table_name);
     stmt := 'SELECT count(*) FROM '||schema_a||'.'||c.table_name
          ||' JOIN '||schema_b||'.'||c.table_name
          || ' USING ('||c.cols||')';
     --dbms_output.put_line('Query '||stmt);
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt INTO n;
     dbms_output.put_line('Found '||n||' overlapping primary keys in table '||c.table_name);
   END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

Comment: I will have to try this tomorrow because I had to go home and I don't have access to the Database. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @wolφi I think your first query was supposed to be a full outer join? There are probably tools that are better suited to comparing database schemas (I believe SQL Developer has that capability, although I've not used it) though, because you'd have to check for columns, constraints, etc etc

Comment: @Boneist: yes, of course, it's a full outer join. Did I mention the QA engineer? ;-) The query is just an example to get AnSuS started. The ERD looks like it is from the federal government, so maybe the both schemas are identical indeed.

Comment: @Boneist Regarding tools: This question came up repeatedly when we had to do a post-migration comparison of an important 100GB database, and we couldn't find a tool that would compare what we really wanted and ignore what we were not interested in. It's been a couple of years, maybe things have improved, though.

Comment: I've used Toad in the past to compare schemas and databases, which was pretty good for what I needed it for (which was all objects in the schemas of interest). I guess it depends on what the OP needs as to whether a tool like Toad or SQL Developer will be of use.

Comment: If I try to run your code @wolφi there is an error:  Fehler(15,115): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "COLUMNS" when expecting one of the following:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    current delete exists prior The symbol "<an identifier> was inserted before "COLUMNS" to continue.

Comment: Ouch! The code is only proof-of-concept code to illustrate what I mean. "COLUMNS" seems to be a reserved word. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, for 350 tables, most probably, would need an `dynamic SQL`.

1. Declare a `CURSOR` or a `COLLECTION - table of VARCHAR2` with all table names.
2. Declare a string variable to build the `dynamic SQL`.
3. `loop` through the entire list of the tables name and, for each table generates a string which will be executed as SQL with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command.
4. The dynamic SQL which will be built, should insert the values from source table into the target table. In case the PK already exists, in target table, should be checked the field which represents the last updated date and if in source table it is bigger than in target table, then perform an update in target table, else, do nothing.