# What is the solution for the errors in this PL/SQL code?

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-errors

This is a follow up question from my first question [How do I merge two simillar database-schema in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059882/how-do-i-merge-two-simillar-database-schema-in-pl-sql)

I have had problems with merging two database-schemata.If you want to know what problems I mean look at my last post (there is a link above). I have elucidated my situation there!

The Code is not from me it is provided by the user @XING:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE copy_table
AS
TYPE obj_nme IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY pls_integer;

--To hold Table name
v_obj_nm obj_nme ;

--To hold Columns of table
v_col_nm obj_nme;

v_othr_col_nm obj_nme;
on_clause VARCHAR2(2000);
upd_clause VARCHAR2(4000);
cntr NUMBER:=0;
v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);

col_list1  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list2  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list3  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list4  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list5  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list6  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list7  VARCHAR2(4000);
col_list8  VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

--Get Source table names
SELECT object_name
BULK COLLECT INTO v_obj_nm
FROM all_objects 
WHERE owner LIKE  'ABBA1@ABBA_QUELLE' -- Replace `RU%` with your Source schema name here
AND object_type = 'TABLE';
--and object_name ='TEST'; --remove this condition if you want this to run for all tables

FOR i IN 1..v_obj_nm.count
loop
--Columns with Constraints 
  SELECT column_name
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_col_nm 
  FROM user_cons_columns
  WHERE table_name = v_obj_nm(i);  

--Columns without Constraints remain columns of table
SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO v_othr_col_nm
FROM (
      SELECT column_name 
      FROM user_tab_cols
      WHERE table_name = v_obj_nm(i)
      MINUS
      SELECT column_name  
      FROM user_cons_columns
      WHERE table_name = v_obj_nm(i));

--Prepare Update Clause  
 FOR l IN 1..v_othr_col_nm.count
  loop
   cntr:=cntr+1;
   upd_clause := 't1.'||v_othr_col_nm(l)||' = t2.' ||v_othr_col_nm(l);    
   upd_clause:=upd_clause ||' and ' ;

   col_list1:= 't1.'||v_othr_col_nm(l) ||',';
   col_list2:= col_list2||col_list1;   

   col_list5:= 't2.'||v_othr_col_nm(l) ||',';
   col_list6:= col_list6||col_list5;

   IF (cntr = v_othr_col_nm.count)
   THEN 
    --dbms_output.put_line('YES');
     upd_clause:=rtrim(upd_clause,' and');
     col_list2:=rtrim( col_list2,',');
     col_list6:=rtrim( col_list6,',');
   END IF;
     dbms_output.put_line(col_list2||col_list6); 
   --dbms_output.put_line(upd_clause);
   END loop;
  --Update caluse ends     

   cntr:=0; --Counter reset  

 --Prepare ON clause  
  FOR k IN 1..v_col_nm.count
  loop
   cntr:=cntr+1;
   --dbms_output.put_line(v_col_nm.count || cntr);
   on_clause := 't1.'||v_col_nm(k)||' = t2.' ||v_col_nm(k);    
   on_clause:=on_clause ||' and ' ;

   col_list3:= 't1.'||v_col_nm(k) ||',';
   col_list4:= col_list4||col_list3;    

   col_list7:= 't2.'||v_col_nm(k) ||',';
   col_list8:= col_list8||col_list7;    

   IF (cntr = v_col_nm.count)
   THEN 
    --dbms_output.put_line('YES');
    on_clause:=rtrim(on_clause,' and');
    col_list4:=rtrim( col_list4,',');
    col_list8:=rtrim( col_list8,',');
   END IF;

   dbms_output.put_line(col_list4||col_list8);
 -- ON clause ends

 --Prepare merge Statement

    v_sql:= 'MERGE INTO ABBA1@abba_ziel.'||v_obj_nm(i)||' t1 --put target     
    schema name before v_obj_nm
          USING (SELECT * FROM ABBA1@abba_quelle.'||v_obj_nm(i)||') t2 --put         
    source schema name before v_obj_nm here 
          ON ('||on_clause||')
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE
          SET '||upd_clause ||              
          ' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT  
          ('||col_list2||','
            ||col_list4||
          ')
          VALUES
          ('||col_list6||','
            ||col_list8||          
           ')';

      dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);   
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
  END loop;    
END loop;
END;
```

> THE CODE WORKS FINE! THANK YOU ALL FOR THE HELP ESPECIALLY XING :)

Comment: Replace `'MERGE INTO '||ABBA1@abba_ziel v_obj_nm(i)||' t1` with `'MERGE INTO ABBA1@abba_ziel.'||v_obj_nm(i)||' t1` and similarly `SELECT * FROM '||ABBA1@abba_quelle v_obj_nm(i)||'` with `SELECT * FROM ABBA1@abba_quelle.'||v_obj_nm(i)||'`

Comment: Run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = american;` in order to get english error messages.

Comment: You left in "schema name here"... which seems to have moved from part of a comment to its own line.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys and @XING I have corrected the code but it still gives me  errors.

Comment: Similarly, the line `for all tables` should be part of the comment on the line above. The line above that, `AND object_type = 'TABLE'`, should end with a semicolon.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson you are right! The errors get less and less :)

Comment: There are issues in the comments inside the dynamic merge statement too, which will show up at run-time rather than compile-time. You haven't fixed the merge statement as XING already mentioned though. And your query against `all_tables` won't find anything in the local DB with a name like that, with the DB link name in it (line 32). You seem to have modified XING's code from your previous question without really understanding it, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right I didn't understand the code because I am a newbie. But I am trying to understand it. If you want to know why I am in this sitiuation where I have to get this done read the comments on my last post (I have elucidated my situation there). Thanks for your help doe!

Comment: @XING The Code works fine now I understand what the problem was thank you very much Sir you have made my week! :D

Comment: @AnSuS All the best but i would recommend you to start reading and try to understand what it's doing. I hope the motive of your adviser would had been to make to learn as i think learning while working is the best way to learn anything.

Comment: @XING you are right. I am going to study your code for the next weeks now. I can't thank you enough!